# typecast BOOL always returns false in iOS 8.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, casting, arm64

I save & retrive the BOOL value in a dictionary using the following methods.

```
[userData setObject:@YES forKey:@"IS_AGENT"];

(BOOL) [userData objectForKey:@"IS_AGENT"];
```

In the above code while retrying the bool value from the dictionary I always get false in the following devices iPhone5s, iPhone5c, iPhone6, iPhone6+ which has iOS 8.1.1 and the same code works fine in iPod Touch which has the same iOS 8.1.1

After googled I came to know that we should not type cast `BOOL` like this because "`BOOL` is a `char`, which is eight bits. If you try to squeeze a value larger than a `char` through `BOOL`, the compiler will happily truncate the upper bits, slicing them off."

Now I fixed the issue simply sending `boolValue` message to a particular object. Check the working code below.

```
[[userData objectForKey:@"IS_AGENT"] boolValue];
```

Ok fine.My question is "Why is it happening in a particular devices (iPhone5s,iPhone5c,iPhone5,iPhone6+) only and not in iPod touch which is having the same iOS 8.1.1?"

Comment: Are you sure you got `NO` on the cited iPhones and `YES` on iPod Touch? I would expect you _always_ get `YES` on those iPhones and _sometimes_ `NO` on the iPod Touch.

Comment: I'm getting always NO on the cited Phones only in iOS 8.1.1. But prior iOS versions on the same cited Phones I'm getting the correct value.. And In iPod Touch I always get the correct value.

Comment: @l0gg3r: What's the reason for the (IMHO destructive) edit?

Comment: @DarkDust as we understand our poster never accepts answers, and keeps editing via changing the meaning of question, so I reverted to initial question.

Comment: @l0gg3r: I object to this. 1) The edits to this question did not alter the meaning of the question in any way. 2) Whether he accepts questions or not is an entirely unrelated matter. Please revert your edit.

Comment: @DarkDust Sure. I should have done that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's my speculation what happened before iOS 8.1.1. Maybe Apple changed the way tagged pointers work here, I haven't had an opportunity to test it yet and haven't found any references whether Apple did change something in this system.

You were casting a *pointer* to a BOOL. Since we're talking about little endian systems here, a pointer like 0x12345678 casted to `char` yields 0x78, when you cast to `BOOL` you get 1 since the byte is not 0. On 64-bit iOS systems with 64-bit binaries, the runtime uses [tagged pointers](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html).

For tagged pointers, the first byte (which are the least significant digits, we're little endian) will always have the last bit set to mark it as a tagged pointer. If you cast that byte to BOOL you'll always get 1/YES.

But for non-tagged pointers, due to aligning, the last four bits are always 0. And by chance it can happen that the other bits of that are are 0 too (in my tests I've only seen multiples of 0x20 so every 8th object would have 0x00). When you cast that to a `BOOL` you'll get YES most of the time and sometimes NO.

As you already found out, the correct way to query the value is `[[userData objectForKey:@"IS_AGENT"] boolValue]` or simply `[userData[@"IS_AGENT"] boolValue]` if your deployment target is iOS >= 6.

Comment: And one more thing, In iOS 8.2 Beta I'm getting the correct value in all the above-mentioned devices. i.e. (BOOL) [userData objectForKey:@"IS_AGENT"]; method gives me the proper value which I saved..

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using `setValue:forKey:` and `valueForKey:` that are KVC methods,
This is strong mistake.

You need to use `setObject:forKey:` and `objectForKey:` to write/read objects from `NSMutableDictionary`.
Also you are casting `NSNumber` to `BOOL`, which will have unexpected behavior.

Instead of that code, use

```
    [userData setObject:@YES forKey:@"IS_AGENT"];
    BOOL isAgent = [[userData objectForKey:@"IS_AGENT"] boolValue];
```

Comment: Sorry, I used objectForKey only not valueForKey, I corrected it in my question... Also, I fixed the issue that is not my question... This issue is only coming in a particular devices not all the iOS 8.1.1 devices.. So It is better to know the reason...

Comment: what? that' a pointer to NSNumber, you are casting NSNumber instance pointer to char which is undefined

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Then It should return NO in all the devices, right? In iPod touch, it is working fine. I get the proper value that what I saved.

Comment: if the architecture is 32 bit then it will return YES always, on 64 bit architecture it will return NO

Comment: even if you will set @NO it will return YES on architecture 32bit

Comment: @l0gg3r: Can you please explain why this should always be YES on 32-bit (I think: sometimes NO) and always NO on 64-bit (I think: always YES)? See my answer, did I miss something?

Comment: even i dont understand the logic , why @NO  will return YES on architecture 32bit ?

Comment: @pawan because you're casting NSNumber pointer (memory address) to BOOL

Comment: @l0gg3r iPhone5c is 32bit only, but In that device also It always returns NO

Comment: @Jirune you are doing same thing as `NSObject *obj = [NSObject new]; NSLog(@"%d", (BOOL)obj);` what will this output? some shit probably. instead of guessing what it will output pointer cast into BOOL, just use `boolValue` and your code will start working. Did you try my provided example?

Comment: @Jirune initially your question was another, so create a new question and ask it there, `When I cast object to BOOL, I get random value`