# iOS 8.1.1 casting @"1" as YES and as NO on different devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, casting

I have an authentication routine that retrieves an encrypted JSON document from an server API for an validation routine.

Once the json message is decrypted it is parsed into a NSDictionary.

Starting with iOS 8.1.1 (and not before) we have some devices in which the following parses to YES and in others it parses to NO.

```
BOOL isValid =  (BOOL)[resp objectForKey : @"IsValid"];
```

The value of the IsValid property in the json dictionary is `{ IsValid: "1" }`
Up to now it has been working fine, since iOS 6, but iOS 8.1.1 broke this on some devices.

I need to understand why this happened, and if there is anything on the device that may cause this issue.

Is there any reason for this and a way to fix it on the device?   I don't want to have to do a new release for many reasons.

Comment: I think what's happening there is `nil` become `NO` and non-nil (e.g. `@YES` and `@NO`) become `YES`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am surprised that the cast has ever worked as intended: casting an object to `BOOL` should result in comparison of the pointer to `nil`, and returning `YES` for all non-nil values. In other words, the cast would produce `YES` if a value is present, be it `@0` or `@1`, and `NO` if the value is missing.

To convert based on the value, use `boolValue` method of `NSNumber` instead:

```
BOOL isValid = [[resp objectForKey : @"IsValid"] boolValue];
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually came to the same conclusion.  This was old code, so I fixed it.   The interesting thing is that it does not always return YES or NO.  It actually depends on the device.  I have several devices that function as 'intended' and others that don't.  It only started happening on iOS 8.1.1, but never before that.

Comment: The answer is correct, but the "shoulds" in this answer are actually not correct (as of 8.1.1). On some devices, the cast produces NO even if the value is present. In other words, casting a non-nil to a BOOL produces NO.

Answer (score 2):

`BOOL` is a `typedef` for `signed char`. When you cast an object pointer to `BOOL`, only the low-order 8 bits are preserved. Those 8 bits could be all zero even if the object pointer is not `nil`, thus a non-`nil` object pointer could become a false `BOOL`. (A `nil` object pointer can't ever become a true `BOOL`, though.)

This has nothing to do with the OS. It's a completely arbitrary result (which is not the same thing as "random").

That's one of many reasons why such a cast is a terrible idea.

Comment: Thanks for the details. It absolutely make sense.  I will have to go through the old code and find gems like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `boolValue` on your `NSString` object. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/boolValue):

> This property is YES on encountering one of "Y", "y", "T", "t", or a
>   digit 1-9—the method ignores any trailing characters. This property is
>   NO if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid decimal text
>   representation of a number.

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate of this post

[typecast BOOL always returns false in iOS 8.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034426/typecast-bool-always-returns-false-in-ios-8-1-1/27082413#27082413)

Do a google search before asking.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the question.  It had a bit of information that explained the inconsistency between some devices returning a YES and others returning the NO.   "if the architecture is 32 bit then it will return YES always, on 64 bit architecture it will return NO –  l0gg3r Nov 20 at 9:21"

Comment: By the way; had I found this in google I wouldn't have posted the question.  Not everyone is as good Googler as you are; and I am probably very bad.  So bear with bad Googlers like me, OK?

Comment: As a pro googler and overall winner of life, let me share my wisdom with you. The trick is to be a bad googler, all you had to do was search "iOS 8.1.1 bool".